# Transferring PC files to MacBook Pro with Lion OS via flash drive

Tags: macos

I have a flash drive with all the files from my old PC.  How do I access / find this flash drive after it is installed, and can I save and use these files (Microsoft Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Outlook primarily)?

Answer (score 1):

**Accessing Flash Drive**

1. Plug the flash drive into your Mac.
2. Open a Finder window. (Double click any folder on your desktop, or click the blue face in the Dock.)
3. Move your mouse over the sidebar on the left-hand side of the Finder window, then place two fingers on the trackpad, and scroll down until you see your flash drive.
4. Click on your flash drive.
5. Open a new Finder window by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>.
6. Find the files you want to copy from your flash drive, and drag them to where you want them copied in the second window.

**Using Files**

You have a number of options here:

- You can get [Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/mac) for Mac, which will enable you to open, edit and save Word, Excel and PowerPoint documents.
- If you prefer something cheaper, there is free open source project called [Libre Office](http://www.libreoffice.org/), which will let you open, edit and save Word, Excel and PowerPoint documents. Unfortunately there are a few features of Word and PowerPoint that it can't handle, but for most basic documents it should suffice.
- If you want a solution that is free, and 100% compatible, you can try Microsoft's new [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/) service. It gives you free access to an online version of Office, and you can export Documents to PDF if you want to print them.
- If you just want to quickly preview documents, and don't mind the formatting being a bit dodgy, you can use QuickLook, by single-clicking on the file in Finder, then pressing <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> You can also double-click them, and open them in Preview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are talking about finding it in Terminal and not Finder as you asked about access /.

Try

```
    cd /Volumes/nameOfFlashDrive
```

That will put you in the / directory of the flash drive. If you don't know the name of the flash drive.

```
    cd /Volumes
```

Then do a ls. Your flash drive should be listed. You could also find the name of the flash drive listed in Finder.

Comment: He didn't mean "access /", he meant "access OR find".